# Are 2RS bearings waterproof?

Tags: washing-machine

I'm looking at bearings for my washing machine. Originally there were 2Z. Just wondering if it would help if choose 2RS instead of 2Z in case when axle seal fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to radial bearings, the z (usually zz or zzs) denotation identifies a non-contact metal shield, the rs identifies a rubber lip seal.  None of them are waterproof, they are just all different levels of water resistant.  It depends more on operating environment, particularly temperature and bypass pressure.

I would use the zz bearings as replacement as that's what was spec'd originally.

Comment: I agree in seeing no reason to change adding that the seal could be a detriment. [Compare Bearing Closures](http://www.astbearings.com/assets/files/Bearing-Closures-Technical-Information-Sheet_ENB-04-0556.pdf)